# How to prevent templates exposure when using SailsJS + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, session, sails.js

I'm using SailsJS and AngularJS to build a web application. The application requires session to keep track of any user's login status. I found this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-todo-app-using-sailsjs-and-angularjs) and add an `index.ejs` view which locates in the `/view` folder. In the `index.ejs` there is a Angular `ng-view` which references to html templates in the `assets/templates` folder.

There is also a `route.js` to handle the template routing in client side:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/profile',{
      templateUrl:'/templates/profile.html',
      controller:'profileController as profileCtrl',
      resolve:{
        checkSession: function($location){
          if(/* Check session status */){
            alert("You can access profile.html");
          }else{
            $location.path('/login');
            alert("You don't have access here");
          }
        }
      }
    })
  .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
  }]);
```

The routing can redirect the user to the login page when requesting for `/profile`. However, when users request for `localhost:1337/templates/profile.html`, they can still get the html, since the `/assets` folder is opened to all users on the internet. Is it possible for me to use Angular `ng-view`, as well as keeping the templates in a safe place (Similar to Sails templates)? For example, when an user is logged in, the server provides some templates, and provides the other templates otherwise.

How to deal with these kinds of permission issues?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no need in adding permissions to template files.since they are only html files. you can provide separate template pages based on user role by using angular templateProvider.